# Removing the default keyboard's interrupt handler in Linux

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, irq

Is there a way to free the default keyboard interrupt handler using `free_irq` from a kernel module?

I've tried to call `free_irq(1, NULL)`, which doesn't work since we I don't know the handler's cookie (2nd argument).

Thanks in advance :)

Update: my kernel version is `4.10.0`.

Comment: Why do you want do this? The irq should be managed by its coresponding dirver. And for the keyboard irq handler, it is not fixed but depends on the device driver used.

Comment: Self-learning. I want to be able to be the only handler in the system.

Comment: maybe what you really want is to hack the input subsystem.